# Java RMI tracing

Tags: java, logging, rmi, trace

Is there a tool which traces & logs all RMI activity of a Java application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are the [JDK RMI debug/logging options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) and I also found this [javaworld article on RMI debugging](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip56.html) - hope they help.

Comment: thanks - adding properties such as -Djava.rmi.server.logcalls=true does the trick :-)

Comment: @javaquestion Isn't it `-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true` (i.e. capital `C`)?

Comment: Seems the defines start with `sun.` nowadays. For Java 6 (change url for Java 7) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

Comment: Also this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/logging.html

Comment: @thomasa88 There are two sets, starting with java and sun respectively.